# Increase in Node Size When Line Width Differs in Tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

In an attempt to produce the below image[image]
I have put the following code together:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,graphs,calc,arrows.meta,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,bending,decorations.markings,matrix,fit,patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \tikzset{
            solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{
                level 1/.style={level distance=12mm,sibling distance=20mm},
                level 2/.style={level distance=12mm,sibling distance=12mm},
                level 3/.style={level distance=12mm,sibling distance=6mm},
            }
            \node (r) [solid node, label = above: {$r\,$\rl{(ریشه)}}]{}
            child{node[solid node, label= left: {$a_{1}$}]{}
                child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node[solid node, label = left: {$b_{1}$}]{}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
            }}
            child{node[solid node, label = left:{$a_{2}$}]{}
                child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node[solid node, label = left:{$b_{2}$}]{}
                    child[missing]
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                }
            }
            child{node (a3) [solid node, label = left:{$a_{3}$}]{}
                child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node (b3)[solid node, label = left:{$b_{3}$}]{}
                    child[missing]}
            }
            child{node (aq)[solid node, label = right:{$a_{q}$}]{}
                child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node (bq) [solid node, label = right:{$b_{q}$}]{}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
                }   
            }
            ;
            \path (a3.east) -- (aq.west) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
            \path (b3.east) -- (bq.west) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
            \tikzset{
                solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
                no edge from this parent/.style={
                    every child/.append style={
                        edge from parent/.style={draw=none}}},
                level 3/.style={yshift=5cm},
                level 4/.style={level distance=10mm} }
            \node[right = 5 of r,align=right] {\rl{سطح $0$ (بیرونی)}} [no edge from this parent]
            child{node {\rl{سطح $1$ (درونی)}}[no edge from this parent]
                child{node {\rl{سطح $2$ (بیرونی)}} [no edge from this parent]
                    child{node {\rl{سطح $3$ (درونی)}}}
            }};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{درخت تناوبی.}
        \label{fig:3-33}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the below image:
[image]
As you can see, the size of the nodes are altered. How can I fix this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Remove `draw` from the definition of `solid node` or specify the line width for the node. When you change the line width, the drawn border is wider and the node looks bigger.

Comment: Please try to provide examples others can compile. I get an error because I don't have the same version of fonts you do. If I remove those lines, I get a different error because `xepersian` doesn't, it seems, enable default fonts. And I have no idea what to substitute. (I expect Noto has something, but which?) Since Persian has no obvious relation to your question, you could avoid these complications by sticking to Latin script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove `draw` from the node style's definition or include a standard `line width`. Because you use the `solid node` style on paths with different line widths, the drawn borders of these nodes have different line widths and some of them look larger than others.

The following is the result of minimising your example and adding `line width=0.4pt` to the definition.

[image: standardised widths]

It would be wise to use a package such as `tikz-qtree` or, better yet, `forest`, but loading it without using it does you no good. Similarly, the problem doesn't depend on the use of non-Latin script and the code doesn't require the majority of the libraries loaded in your preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,line width=0.4pt,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    level 1/.style={level distance=12mm,sibling distance=20mm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=12mm,sibling distance=12mm},
    level 3/.style={level distance=12mm,sibling distance=6mm},
  }
  \node (r) [solid node, label = above: {$r\,$xxx}]{}
  child{node[solid node, label= left: {$a_{1}$}]{}
    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node[solid node, label = left: {$b_{1}$}]{}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
    }}
  child{node[solid node, label = left:{$a_{2}$}]{}
    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node[solid node, label = left:{$b_{2}$}]{}
      child[missing]
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
    }
  }
  child{node (a3) [solid node, label = left:{$a_{3}$}]{}
    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node (b3)[solid node, label = left:{$b_{3}$}]{}
      child[missing]}
  }
  child{node (aq)[solid node, label = right:{$a_{q}$}]{}
    child[edge from parent/.style={draw, line width=0.7mm}]{node (bq) [solid node, label = right:{$b_{q}$}]{}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
      child[edge from parent/.style={draw, thin}]{node[solid node]{}}
    }   
  }
  ;
  \path (a3.east) -- (aq.west) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
  \path (b3.east) -- (bq.west) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
  \tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
    no edge from this parent/.style={
      every child/.append style={
        edge from parent/.style={draw=none}}},
    level 3/.style={yshift=5cm},
    level 4/.style={level distance=10mm} }
  \node[right = 5 of r,align=right] {xxx} [no edge from this parent]
  child{node {xxx}[no edge from this parent]
    child{node {xxx} [no edge from this parent]
      child{node {xxx}}
    }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`forest` (or even `tikz-qtree`) would enable you to use a less cluttered syntax and more powerful customisation, including greater automation. Even simply defining and applying `styles` with plain Ti*k*Z would make your code clearer and more flexible.

For example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705271/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Arian: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/705249/
\newcounter{forlevel}
\renewcommand* \theforlevel{\alph{forlevel}}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={level label}{},
  last level label/.style={label={right:{${#1}_{q}$}}},
  other level label/.style 2 args={label={left:{${#1}_{#2}$}}},
  fancy tree/.style={%
    for tree={
      solid node,
      tier/.option=level,
      fit=band,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={%
        fake=root,
        last leaf,
        branch'={%
          while={%
            >On>{level}{1}%
          }{%
            parent,
            TeX={\setcounter{forlevel}{\foresteoption{level}}},
            level label/.expanded=\theforlevel,
            last level label/.option=level label,
            tikz+={\path () -- (!previous on tier) node [midway] {$\cdots$};}%
          },
          while nodewalk valid={previous on tier}{%
            previous on tier,
            TeX={\setcounter{forlevel}{\foresteoption{level}}},
            level label/.expanded=\theforlevel,
            other level label/.process={OO{level label}{n}}
          }%
        }%
      }{},
    },
    before packing={%
      tempdima/.max={> OO OO  w4+d  {s}{!u1.s}  {s sep}{!u.n children} {(##1-##2)+##3*(##4-1)} }{leaves},
      for children={minimum width=\foresteregister{tempdima},typeset node},
    },
    before drawing tree={%
      for children={minimum width=0pt,typeset node},
    },
  },
}
\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,line width=0.4pt,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  fancy tree,
  [,label={above:{${r}$ xxx}}
    [[[][][][]]]
    [[[,phantom][][]]]
    [[]]
    [[[][][]]]
  ]
  \coordinate (e) at (current bounding box.east);
  \foreach \i/\j in {!r/xxx,!rl/xxx,!rll/xxx,!rlll/xxx}
  \node [anchor=west,xshift=10pt] at (\i -| e) {\j};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```